# Referencing Named Table Column in VBA

Tags: vba, runtime-error, excel-2016

I have several tables with fastener data that I'm trying to pull information from based on what's in the main input table on a separate spreadsheet. I have a formula that works, but as I add different fastener tables (I'm up to 5 with at least 5 more planned), the nested IF formula is getting unruly. I decided to try to convert the formula to VBA and I'm getting an error: Run-time error '5':  Invalid procedure or argument.  It doesn't like how I'm trying to reference a named column in my fastener tables.  The formula that I am trying to convert is included below. I haven't yet determined how best to set up the If statement so that if the user selected IFF, it would switch to using the IFF table, but that's another post (the example below is a super simplified version of what I have).

```
Dim tbl_Solid As ListObject
    
    Dim Rep_Fast_Type
    Dim Incoming_Dia
    Dim BP_Max_Dia
    Dim Test_Dia
    Dim Rep_Fast
    Dim Test_Value
    Dim i
    
    Set tbl_Solid = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fastener DB").ListObjects("tbl_Solid")
    
    i = 1
    
    Incoming_Dia = [tbl_Input].Cells(i, 2)
    BP_Max_Dia = [tbl_Input].Cells(i, 3)
    Rep_Fast_Type = [tbl_Input].Cells(i, 4)
    
    If Incoming_Dia > BP_Max_Dia Then
            Test_Dia = Incoming_Dia
        Else
            Test_Dia = BP_Max_Dia
    End If
    
'Run-time error at all [tbl_Hptc].Range("Fastener").
    If Rep_Fast_Type = "Solid" Then
          With WorksheetFunction
        Rep_Fast = .Index([tbl_Hptc].Range("Fastener"), _
            .Aggregate(15, 6, .IfError( _
                Rows([tbl_Hptc].Range("Fastener")) / _
                    ((Test_Dia >= [tbl_Hptc].Range("Dia Min")) * (Test_Dia <= [tbl_Hptc].Range("Dia Max"))), _
                        Rows([tbl_Hptc].Range("Fastener")) / (Test_Dia <= [tbl_Hptc].Range("Dia Min"))), 1))
    End With
    End If
    
    'To test values
    MsgBox "Incoming diameter is " & Incoming_Dia & vbCrLf & "B/P max diameter is " & BP_Max_Dia & vbCrLf & "Test diameter is " & Test_Dia & vbCrLf & "Repair fastener type is " & Rep_Fast_Type & vbCrLf & "Repair Fastener is " & Rep_Fast
```

Old Excel Formula:

```
=IF([@[rep type]]="Solid",INDEX(tbl_Solid[[#All],[Fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/(([@diameter]>=tbl_Solid[min])*([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[max])),ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[min])),1)),IF([@[rep type]]="IFF",INDEX(tbl_IFF[[#All],[Fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(tbl_IFF[Fastener])/(([@diameter]>=tbl_IFF[min])*([@diameter]<=tbl_IFF[max])),ROW(tbl_IFF[Fastener])/([@diameter]<=tbl_IFF[min])),1))))
```

Screenshot of Data
[image: Screenshot of Data]

Answer (score 0):

The lines using `[]` to reference a range are actually a shortcut to the `Evaluate` method.   You don't want to use that.

Instead, leverage the `ListObject`.  Eg

```
tbl_Solid.ListColumns("Fastener")
```

Returns a `ListColumn` object

```
tbl_Solid.ListColumns("Fastener").DataBodyRange
```

Returns the range for that column, excluding the header

Comment: Why do the brackets work for setting the incoming and B/P diameters and the repair fastener type variables, but not when trying to determine the fastener?

Also, when I changed the code to use your suggestions, I received a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.  Not sure if you can help.  I'll keep looking for a solution.  Thanks!